# How to reset RxJS distinct in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I need implement infinite scroll because my backend respond is restricted for only 100 items. So on first page attempt I receive 100 items from backend. And on every scroll to the end of page I need call endpoint for another 100 items.

In my child component (`BpHistoryListInfiniteComponent`) I set `data-load` attribute for tracking when 100. element come in view. And then with `IntersectionObserver` set in Subject(`pageByScroll$`) value of data-load attribute. My `pageByScroll$` need to start with 0 (for first page attempt) and I using `distinct()` because I need `distinct` already loaded items, and then emit that value to my parent component.

But after using one of filters in parent component I need to reset `index` value to 0 and send that and filters value to backend (and receive only 100 items), and then if user scroll to the bottom I need to increase my `index` from 0 again but `distinct()` not allow me that.

I need somehow reset distinct values.

//html part of child component

```
<div #infiniteScrollMadness class="column">
  <div *ngFor="let item of history; let i = index" class="list" [attr.data-load]="(i + 1) % 100 == 0 ? (i + 1) : null">
    <span>{{ item.id }}</span>
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts part of child component

```
export class BpHistoryListInfiniteComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    public pageByScroll$ = new Subject<number>();

    @ViewChild("infiniteScrollMadness")
    private scrollHost: ElementRef;

    @Input()
    history: HistoryModel;

    @Input()
    highlight: string;

    @Output()
    index = new EventEmitter<number>();

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
            entries => {
                entries
                    .filter(element => element.isIntersecting)
                    .forEach(element => {
                        this.pageByScroll$.next(
                            element.target.attributes["data-load"].value
                        );
                    });
            },
            {
                threshold: 0.1
            }
        );
        const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            mutations.forEach(mutation => {
                if (!mutation.addedNodes || mutation.type !== "childList") {
                    return;
                }
                const nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(mutation.addedNodes, 0);

                nodes.filter(node => node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    .forEach((element: Element) => {
                        if (element.attributes["data-load"]) {
                            this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
                                intersectionObserver.observe(element);
                            });
                        }
                    });
            });
        });

        mutationObserver.observe(this.scrollHost.nativeElement, {
            childList: true
        });

        this.pageByScroll$.pipe(
            startWith(0),
            distinct()
        ).subscribe(index => this.index.emit(index));
    }

    constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}
}
```

`pageByScroll$` stream:

- first page attempt => value: 0

- scroll to bottom (+100) => value: 100

- scroll to bottom (+100) => value: 200

- scroll to bottom (+100) => value: 300

- use one of filter => value: 0

- scroll to bottom (+100) => value: 100 

- scroll to bottom (+100) => value: 200

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could handle it like this

```
this.resets$ = new Subject();
this.resets$.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  switchMap(() => this.pageByScroll$.pipe(
    startWith(0),
    distinct()
  ))
).subscribe(this.index);
```

this wil "scope" `distinct` operator to `switchMap` and you can manually reset it by `this.resets$.next(null)`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I need